# GASのmatchメソッドに変数を格納して使うことはできるのでしょうか？

Tags: google-apps-script

GASで以下のことをしようとしております。

① スプレッドシートの、特定の1箇所のセルにある文字列をGASで取得
② 別のスプレッドシートの特定の1列にある、その文字列を含む1箇所のセルを検索
③ そのセルがある行の2行目に「成功」と表示

①で取得する文字列ですが、毎回記入する内容が変わっても大丈夫なように、GASのスクリプトでは変数に代入して使いたいです。

はじめは `match` メソッドと正規表現を使えばいいかと思い試しておりましたが、正規表現では毎回内容が変わる文字列には対応できないとわかり、別の方法を探しておりました。

そこで、ひとまず手探りで調べながら以下のコードを書いてみました。↓↓↓↓

```js
function myFunction() {

var anotherSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1tobnoaxHbXMZBBiWv4LDLnMsvwljlpwG-CdtMGDKcuE');     
var ss = anotherSheet.getActiveSheet();                                                         
var value = ss.getRange(1,1).getValue();

var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

if(thisSheet.getRange("A1:A").match(value)){
thisSheet.getRange("B1:B").setValue("成功");

}
}
```

もちろんこのままではエラーとなってしまいます。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
thisSheet.getRange(...).match is not a function
```

エラーメッセージからして、 `match` メソッドの書き方に問題があるのかなと思うのですが、上記のコードのように、 `If` 文の `match` のmatchメソッド()内に変数を格納はできないのでしょうか？

また、冒頭③の「成功」と表記するセルの指定の仕方がわからず、「シートの2行目」という意味で「 B1:B 」というおかしな指定でコードを書いております。

この二つが主な原因でエラーとなっているのかなと推測していますが、解決策がまだ見出せずにおります。
よろしければ、このコードの正しい書き方を教えていただけないでしょうか？

GASに慣れておらず未熟な質問内容ですが、ご教示いただけると幸いです

Comment: こちら、質問を行う際に、「文字コード」のタグを利用するのを、お控えいただけますでしょうか。というのも、「文字コード」とは、 UTF-8 や Shift-JIS など、文字化けなどに関する質問をする際に利用される想定のタグであり、「文字列をプログラム中で利用している際に利用するタグ」ではないからです。

Comment: 大変失礼いたしました。以後気をつけたいと思います。